# parse string as conditions to filter pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, operators

Hi I have a pandas dataframe, I have a column A.

```
data = pandas.DataFrame()
data['A']= [numpy.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]) for i in range(10)]
```

I want to add a column B condition on A (when A =1 then B=0, when A>5 then B=1) instead of using:

```
data.loc[data['A']==1,'B']=0
data.loc[data['A']>5, 'B']=1
```

Here I want to create a function to do this given the condition as a dict: {'A=1':0,'A>5':1} so I could use add_column({'A=1':0,'A>5':1}, 'B') to do the code above. I am thinking it is tricky to deal with the operators, any good idea?

```
def add_column(condition_dict, NewColumnName):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may be efficient ways to do it, one possible way might be to use `eval` function.

Creating input `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame()
data['A']= [np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]) for i in range(10)]
print(data)
```

Input `df`:

```
   A
0  4
1  3
2  3
3  1
4  1
5  2
6  3
7  6
8  2
9  1
```

Now, a function is created such that it `iterates` through each row of `dataframe` and `condition_dict` and when `row` evaluation matches `value` is stored in list for corresponding row which is updated for `new column`. If none of the condition matches then with default it will `None`:

```
def add_column(df, condition_dict, NewColumnName):
    new_values = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # if none of the condition matches then put default value
        default_value = None
        # iterate through each condition to check if any matches
        for key, value in condition_dict.items():
            expression = 'row.' + key
            if(eval(expression)):
                default_value = value
        # add corresponding rows new value for new column        
        new_values.append(default_value)

    df[NewColumnName] = new_values
```

Now, to call the function:

```
add_column(data, {'A==1':0, 'A>5':1}, 'B')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   A    B
0  4  NaN
1  3  NaN
2  3  NaN
3  1  0.0
4  1  0.0
5  2  NaN
6  3  NaN
7  6  1.0
8  2  NaN
9  1  0.0
```